# How to search for specific cards using a searchbar

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want that when you type something in my searchbar, only the cards with that name stay on the page and everything else disappears. I have tried some things but i never succeeded. Here is the code I am working with.

The navbar itself:

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mysearch" class="search_card"> 
    <div class="card">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="music-description">
            <h1>Mijn Muziek</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="searchbar">
              <input class="search_input" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Zoeken" >

            <a href="#" class="search_icon"><i class="fas fa-search fa-lg"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="my_music_new">
      <%if logged_in?(:site_admin)%> 
        <%= link_to 'Nieuw', new_my_music_path %>
      <% end %>
    </div>      
    <%= render @my_musics %>
  </div>
</body>
```

@my_musics contains the cards.

_my_musics:

```
<body>
  <div class="music_card">  
    <div class="card data-id="<%= my_music.id %>">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="my_music_img">
            <% if my_music.image == ""%>
              <%= image_tag "img_not_found" %>
            <% elsif my_music.image.length < 8 %> 
              <%= image_tag "img_not_found" %>
            <% else %>
              <img src="<%= my_music.image %>">
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <div class="my_music_title">
            <h2><%= my_music.title %></h2>
          </div>
          <div class="my_music_description">
            <p><%= markdown my_music.description %></p>
          </div>
          <% if my_music.page_number > 0 %>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="my_music_pages">
                  <% if my_music.page_number > 0 %>
                    <p>Paginas: <%= my_music.page_number %></p><br><br><br>
                  <% else %>
                  <% end %>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="my_music_year">
                  <% if my_music.year > 0 %>
                    <p>Uitgekomen in: <%= my_music.year %></p><br><br><br>
                  <% else %>
                  <% end %>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          <% else %>
            <div class="my_music_year">
              <% if my_music.year > 0 %>
                <p>Uitgekomen in: <%= my_music.year %></p><br><br><br>
              <% else %>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
          <div class="down_lis_buttons">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <div class="my_music_listen"> 
                  <% if my_music.listen == "" %>
                    <div class="my_music_listen_1">
                      <a class="fab fa-youtube fa-3x"></a>

                    </div>
                  <% elsif my_music.listen.length < 5 %>
                    <div class="my_music_listen_1">
                      <a class="fab fa-youtube fa-3x"></a>

                    </div>
                  <% else %>
                    <div class="my_music_listen_2">
                      <a class="fab fa-youtube fa-3x" href="<%= my_music.listen %>"></a>
                    </div>
                  <% end %>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <div class="my_music_download">
                  <% if my_music.download.length == 0 %>
                    <div class="my_music_download_1">
                      <a class="fas fa-file-download fa-3x"></a>
                    </div>
                  <% elsif my_music.download.length < 5 %> 
                    <div class="my_music_download_1">
                      <a class="fas fa-file-download fa-3x"></a>
                    </div>

                  <% else %> 
                    <% if my_music.reserved == 1 %> 
                      <% if logged_in?(:special, :site_admin) %>
                        <div class="my_music_download_2">
                          <a class="fas fa-file-download fa-3x" href="<%= my_music.download %>" download></a>
                        </div>
                      <% else %>
                        <div class="tool-tip">
                          <a class="fas fa-file-download fa-3x">
                          </a>
                          <span>
                            U hebt niet de vereiste toestemming om deze actie uit te voeren.
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      <% end %>
                    <% elsif current_user.is_a?(GuestUser) %>
                      <div class="tool-tip">
                        <a class="fas fa-file-download fa-3x">
                        </a>
                        <span>
                          Meld u aan om deze actie uit te voeren. 
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    <% else %>
                      <div class="my_music_download_2">
                        <a class="fas fa-file-download fa-3x" href="<%= my_music.download %>" download></a>
                      </div>

                    <% end %>
                  <% end %>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="my-musics-button">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                    <%= link_to fa_icon('book size: 2x'), toggle_status_my_music_path(my_music), style: my_music_status_color(my_music) if logged_in?(:site_admin)  %>

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                    <%if logged_in?(:site_admin)%> 
                    <div class="button" role="button">
                      <%= link_to 'Bewerken', edit_my_music_path(my_music), style: 'text-decoration: none;' %>
                    </div>
                    <% end %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                    <%if logged_in?(:site_admin)%>
                    <div class="button" role="button">
                      <%= link_to 'Verwijderen', my_music, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, style: 'text-decoration: none;'%>
                    </div>
                    <% else %>
                    <% end %>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Is there a simple way of doing this?
Thank you!

Comment: Presumably, you've tried some javascript. If so, can you show what you've tried? If not, can you describe what you *have* tried?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54169521/how-can-i-search-for-specific-cards-by-their-title-and-body

Comment: Maybe you can use this https://listjs.com/. It might help you to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you! It works now.